# create a foreign key on a primary key of another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE public.impiegato(
   CF varchar NOT NULL,
   codice_reparto int4 NOT NULL,
    mansione varchar NULL,
CONSTRAINT impiegato_pkey PRIMARY KEY (CF),
CONSTRAINT impiegato_fkey FOREIGN KEY (codice_reparto) REFERENCES   reparto(codice),
);

CREATE TABLE public.reparto(
codice int4 NOT NULL,
nome varchar NULL,
cf_responsabile varchar NULL,
nome_responsabile varchar NULL UNIQUE,
CONSTRAINT reparto_pkey PRIMARY KEY (codice),
CONSTRAINT reparto_cf_responsabile_fkey FOREIGN KEY (cf_responsabile) REFERENCES impiegato(CF)
);
```

When i run the sql code it tells me that the impiegato table doesn't exist. Can I run a foreign key on a primary key of another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referenced table must exists when a foreign key is declared.

Since in your case the two tables reference each other, it's not possible to solve this by simply creating the right one first.

You have to create the first one (any of them) first without the foreign key constraint, create the second on and then add the foreign key constraint to the first one.

Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE public.impiegato
             (cf varchar
                 NOT NULL,
              codice_reparto int4
                             NOT NULL,
              mansione varchar
                       NULL,
              CONSTRAINT impiegato_pkey
                         PRIMARY KEY (cf));

CREATE TABLE public.reparto
             (codice int4
                     NOT NULL,
              nome varchar
                   NULL,
              cf_responsabile varchar
                              NULL,
              nome_responsabile varchar
                                NULL
                                UNIQUE,
              CONSTRAINT reparto_pkey
                         PRIMARY KEY (codice),
              CONSTRAINT reparto_cf_responsabile_fkey
                         FOREIGN KEY (cf_responsabile)
                                     REFERENCES impiegato
                                                (cf));

ALTER TABLE public.impiegato
            ADD CONSTRAINT impiegato_fkey
                           FOREIGN KEY (codice_reparto)
                                       REFERENCES reparto
                                                  (codice);
```

Unfortunately, you didn't tag your DBMS. From some details I guessed it might be Postgres and the code above hence is Postgres code. If you don't use Postgres, you might need to adapt the `ALTER TABLE` statement, they can differ between DBMS.

Comment: tank you. But how add data in this table?When i add data Postgres don't work

Comment: @ElenaRondina: That's actually another question, *this* one is solved I guess. But some pointer: Either a) first insert into `reparto` with `NULL` for `cf_responsabile`, after all it's defined to allow `NULL`s, then insert into `impiegato` and update `reparto` with the right the foreign key. Or b) search for feature of deferrable constraints Postgres offers. Defined the constraints as deferrable and defer their checks to the end of the transaction that inserts the records.

Comment: Thank you. Now Postgres work. My teacher give me a strange exercise: multiple employees work in a department but an employee can only work in one department. Also department can only have one manager (who is an employee) I solved it by the tables wrote above but I don't know if it is right.
basically, department and employee refer to themselves. By the way  thanks you

Comment: @ElenaRondina: Nothing strange about such a scenario. Unfortunately I don't speak the (natural) language this is in, so I'm not use what is what. But if `reparto` means department, `impiegato` means employee and `cf_responsabile` manager then it's OK in general I think. Only if `nome_responsabile` is the manager's name, it doesn't belong in `reparto`. Employees names should be stored only in `impiegato`. You can get the name of a manger by looking up the record there.

Comment: it is as you write reparto means department, impiegato means employee and cf_responsabile manager. Now everything works. Thank you so much :)